# SQL Server Date Formats (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.MMM)

Tags: sql-server-2008

Update:
i am still getting this `(4/14/2012 2:44:01 PM)`  result after trying this

```
 select convert(varchar(30), '4/14/2012 2:44:01 PM',121)
```

**End Update**

what format should i use in order to get this result set:

```
2012-04-14 14:44:01.683
```

i tried using this but does not show the micro/milli seconds

```
select convert(varchar(23), '4/14/2012 2:44:01 PM',120)
```

gets me this result:

```
4/14/2012 2:44:01 PM
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close - in the chapter on [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) on MSDN Books Online, you've missed the right answer by one line.... you can use style no. 121 (*ODBC canonical (with milliseconds)*) to get the result you're looking for:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 121)
```

This gives me the output of:

```
2012-04-14 21:44:03.793
```

**Update:** based on your updated question - of course this won't work - you're converting a string (this: `'4/14/2012 2:44:01 PM'` is **just a string** - it's **NOT** a datetime!) to a string......

You need to **first** convert the string you have to a `DATETIME` and **THEN** convert it back to a string!

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST('4/14/2012 2:44:01 PM' AS DATETIME), 121)
```

Now you should get:

```
2012-04-14 14:44:01.000
```

All zeroes for the milliseconds, obviously, since your original values didn't include any ....

Comment: i have updated my question, if you use the `GetDate()` yes the result showing with milli seconds but if you try what i have posted the date time which is '4/14/2012 2:44:01 PM' i am still not getting milli seconds

Comment: or is there a way to get rid of pm/am ? i am looking for a best pratice i would have easily trim the string which dont want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your date string in datetime format , as below

```
select convert(varchar(23), convert(datetime,'4/14/2012 2:44:01 PM'),120)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product. I have removed your blog link so that your post is not mistaken for spam. Please do not continue to link to your blog in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(varchar(30), CAST('4/14/2012 2:44:01 PM' As DATETIME),121)
```